# How to create a nested data in json in the given format using unity c#

Tags: c#, json, api, unity-game-engine, nested

I am still learning , Here is the given format -

> {"table": "userdata","data":{ "walletaddress": "0x15be4040E5147Cd9F8Cc4600C9D6Da720F2631Ea", "character": "alice","gender": "male","name": "test_joe"}}

Here is my code -

```
public class PlayerData
{
    public string walletaddress;
    public string name;
    public string gender;
    public int character;
    
}

public IEnumerator POST()
{
    string url = "xyz";

    PlayerData playerData = new PlayerData();
    playerData.character = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PlayerAvatar");
    //data.userEggCount = 0;
    playerData.gender = PlayerPrefs.GetString("PlayerGender");
    playerData.name = PlayerPrefs.GetString(playerNamePrefKey);
    playerData.walletaddress = "123";//PlayerPrefs.GetString("Account");
    string jsonStringTrial = JsonUtility.ToJson(playerData);
    Debug.Log(jsonStringTrial);

    using(UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Put(url, jsonStringTrial))
    {
        request.method = UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPOST;
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        if(request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.Log("Sent Data Successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Data not Sent");
        }
    }
```

this gives me data in this format -

> {"walletaddress":"123","name":"Darshan","gender":"1","character":1}

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: well you JSON and c# data structure do not match .... -> https://json2csharp.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should construct your models to achieve json same as `{"table": "userdata","data":{ "walletaddress": "0x15be4040E5147Cd9F8Cc4600C9D6Da720F2631Ea", "character": "alice","gender": "male","name": "test_joe"}}` to,

Do some adjustment if required but this would work nearly or 100% as you need,

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Data
{
    public string walletaddress;
    public string character;
    public string gender;
    public string name;

}

[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{
    public string table;
    public Data data;
}

public IEnumerator POST()
{
    string url = "xyz";

    PlayerData playerData = new PlayerData();
    playerData.table = "<valuetable>"
    playerData.data.character = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PlayerAvatar");
    //data.userEggCount = 0;
    playerData.data.gender = PlayerPrefs.GetString("PlayerGender");
    playerData.data.name = PlayerPrefs.GetString(playerNamePrefKey);
    playerData.data.walletaddress = "123";//PlayerPrefs.GetString("Account");
    string jsonStringTrial = JsonUtility.ToJson(playerData);
    Debug.Log(jsonStringTrial);

    using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Put(url, jsonStringTrial))
    {
        request.method = UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPOST;
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        if (request.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.Log("Sent Data Successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Data not Sent");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will not work. Unity built in `JsonUtility` does not serialize properties and non-serializable custom classes

Comment: Thanks it worked, you just forgot to initialise the Data class.